# Intellij is not showing SceneBuilder properly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder, intellij-plugin

I have just installed SceneBuilder in IntelliJ for JavaFX but is not showing properly. please check the below image, somehow it messes up with font.

I use MacOs BigSur version 11.3
ItelliJ version: 2021.1 CE

Does anyone know how to fix the issue?

Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the issue created for this bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266524

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, It says that I have to use a stand-alone version, so it means there is no fixed solution for this bug as today to use it in the Intellij idea 
I reinstalled Intellij and SceneBuilder but no chance :(